# C++ Discard qualifiers on iterator (const)

Tags: c++, list, iterator, constants

I got a problem with a iterator. When i compile my project i keep getting this error.

```
Kitchen.cpp: In member function ‘void Kitchen::If_Cook_Ok(const Order&) const’:
    Kitchen.cpp:45:33: error: passing ‘const Order’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::list<IngredType::Ingredient> Order::getIngredient()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
    Kitchen.cpp:45:70: error: passing ‘const Order’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::list<IngredType::Ingredient> Order::getIngredient()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

I already tried to put constness on the function member, but i keep getting this error. Here is the code

The Order class has as member variable a std::list witch is returned by the getter getIngredients()

```
void    Kitchen::If_Cook_Ok(const Order &order) const
{
  std::cout << "congratulations you barely made it" << std::endl;
  std::list<IngredType::Ingredient>::const_iterator it;

  for (it = order.getIngredient().begin(); it != order.getIngredient().end(); ++it)
    {
      std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`order` is a `const Order&`. Thus, you could only call const methods of `Order` class. And it appears that `Order::getIngredient()` is not const.

Comment: As i responded just above you got it just right, it was the other member function that wasn't a const one, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The`Order` parameter in the method `If_Cook_Ok` is `const`, so you can only call `cons`t methods on this object. Perhaps the `getIngredients()` method is not `const`. Try adding `const` on that method.

Comment: Indeed it was the other method that wasn't const thank you very much.